# Проблема с INSTALLED_APPS в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Возникло желание объединить все приложения моего проекта в одну папку под названием apps, то есть имеется основная папка проекта, в ней находится еще две папки, а именно apps и папка с названием моего проекта, так же в основной папке находится файл **manage.py**.

Так вот, в документации к Django  сказано, что в INSTALLED_APPS можно указывать как корневой каталог самого приложения, так и наследника класса django.apps.AppConfig, в котором есть обязательное поле **name**, обозначающее имя добавляемого приложения. При указании директории приложения, то есть добавления в INSTALLED_APPS строки *apps.<название приложения>* тестовый сервер без ругани запускается и проглатывает модели внутри, но если же я пишу *apps.<название приложения>.apps.<название приложения>Config*, то есть указываю класс-наследник от AppConfig. В результате при запуске тестового сервера происходит ошибка:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'apps.school'. Check that 'apps.school.apps.SchoolConfig.name' is correct.

Comment: Ну написано же не корректное имя. ('apps.schыool)

Comment: Вы уверены, что `schыool` так и должно быть `schыool`?

Comment: Кириллица и латиница в перемешку

Comment: И кстати переименуйте `apps` во что-нибудь более внятное, например в название вашего проекта

Comment: Исправил, не было в перемешку, просто отредачил плохо

Comment: А где конкретно ваш «класс-наследник от AppConfig» расположен-то? И покажите его содержимое?